# Splitting an attribute into individual attributes logically

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an xml file which has some links as follows:

```
<link href="#ap45-bib-0004"/>
<link href="#ap45-bib-0005"/>
```

The corresponding link is present in the citation like:

```
<bib xml:id="ap5-bib-0004">....</bib>
```

and so on.

I am using XSLT 2.0. I needed to display just `4` and `5` (the last number) in the html view.
I have done this using the substring-after function. I have linked it to its corresponding citation as well.

But there are some links as follows:

```
<link href="#ap45-bib-0001 #ap45-bib-0002"/>
<link href="#ap45-bib-0007 #ap45-bib-0008 #ap45-bib-0009"/>
```

I need to diplay this as following in my html file:

`1, 2` and `7, 8, 9` respectively.

I tried doing this using the substring function. Any idea how to go about this. As there can be any number of links inside one href. And the immediate next issue is how will it link to its corresponding citation. Really confused. Help of any kind would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the XPath method tokenize to get a sequence of references:

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_tokenize.html

```
tokenize('#ap45-bib-0007 #ap45-bib-0008 #ap45-bib-0009', ' ')
```

This will return the sequence

```
('#ap45-bib-0007', '#ap45-bib-0008', '#ap45-bib-0009')
```

Then iterate over this sequence and extract the numbers as you have done before:

```
for $token in tokenize('#ap45-bib-0007 #ap45-bib-0008 #ap45-bib-0009', ' ') 
return substring-after($token, '000')
```

Answer (score 1):

As for linking from `<link href="#ap45-bib-0001 #ap45-bib-0002"/>` to `<bib xml:id="ap45-bib-0001">bib 1</bib>`, assuming XSLT 2.0 you can simply use `id(for $ref in tokenize(@href, ' ') return substring($ref, 2))` to find the `bib` elements with an `xml:id` listed as the `href` attribute of your `link` element.